# how to print exact html tags from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json data Sample

```
[{
    "Field1": "<header class=\"main-header dark-bg\">\n\t\t<div class=\"row\">\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"col-xl-3\">\n<a class=\"icons-darkbg-slogan main-header__slogan\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/\" data-event_title=\"Header Home::Slogan\" href=\"/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"DWS Homepage\"><img src=\"/globalassets/images/logos/dws_logo_global.svg\" class=\"icon-svg hide-for-print\" alt=\"dws_logo_global\"></a>\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t<nav class=\"col-xl-9 hide-lg main-header__group\">\n\n        <ul class=\"list-inline pipe-separator text-medium pull-right hide-for-print\">\n\n\n \n\n\n    <li class=\"\">\n        <a data-event_component_headline=\"\" data-event_component_name=\"header-navigation\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/das-unternehmen/\" data-event_title=\"Über Uns\" href=\"/das-unternehmen/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"Über Uns\" class=\"\">Über Uns</a>\n    </li>\n\n    <li class=\"\">\n        <a data-event_component_headline=\"\" data-event_component_name=\"header-navigation\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/service/\" data-event_title=\"Service\" href=\"/service/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"Service\" class=\"\">Service</a>\n    </li>\n\n    <li class=\"\">\n        <a data-event_component_headline=\"\" data-event_component_name=\"header-navigation\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/service/dws-direkt/\" data-event_title=\"DWS Direkt\" href=\"/service/dws-direkt/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"DWS Direkt\" class=\"\">DWS Direkt</a>\n    </li>\n\n    <li class=\"\">\n        <a data-event_component_headline=\"\" data-event_component_name=\"header-navigation\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"external link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"https://depot.dws.de/\" data-event_title=\"DWS Depot Login\" href=\"https://depot.dws.de/\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"DWS Depot Login\" class=\"\">DWS Depot Login</a>\n    </li>\n\n    <li class=\"\">\n        <a data-event_component_headline=\"\" data-event_component_name=\"header-navigation\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"internal page link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"/service/berater-welt/\" data-event_title=\"Berater\" href=\"/service/berater-welt/\" target=\"_self\" title=\"Berater\" class=\"\">Berater</a>\n    </li>\n\n    <li class=\"\">\n        <a data-event_component_headline=\"\" data-event_component_name=\"header-navigation\" data-event_engagement=\"\" data-event_linktype=\"external link\" data-event_source=\"DAM|active|de|de|/\" data-event_target=\"https://dws.com/de/\" data-event_title=\"DWS Group\" href=\"https://dws.com/de/\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"DWS Group\" class=\"\">DWS Group</a>\n    </li>\n            \n\t\t\t\n        </ul>\n\n\t\t\t\t</nav>\n\t\t</div>\n\n\t\t<div class=\"space-9 hide-md\"></div>\n\t</header>"
  }]
```

I want to display field1's corresponding all HTML tags in table, i tried this code on ajax success

```
var html = '<table border="1">';
        html += '<th id="keypress">KEY</th>';
        html += '<th>VALUE</th>';

    for (var key in mainObject) {
          var innerObject = mainObject[key]
          for (var innerKey in innerObject) {

            html += '<tr>';
            var t = innerObject[innerKey];
            var ud = $(t).attr('class');

            html += '<td>' + innerKey + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + $(t).html() + '</td>';

            html += '</table>';

 displayResources.html(html)
```

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5oUJ.png)

i have used .text(), $.parsejson and json.stringify() but couldn't able to get output. Please help me on this. check the image for reference

Comment: So you want to show `<th>VALUE</th>` instead of just `VALUE`?

Comment: i want to display html tags in td . ex: <div class="one"></div><div class="two"></div>.. so on. Please check the output screenshot for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.createElement` to create `tr` and `td`, then append your text without parsing it into `HTMLElement` with `.innerText`

```js
var html = '<table border="1">';
var mainObject = [{"Field1":"<div class=\"row\">something else here</div>"}]
html += '<tr>'
html += '<th id="keypress">KEY</th>';
html += '<th>VALUE</th>';
html += '</tr>';

for (var key in mainObject) {
  var innerObject = mainObject[key];
  for (var innerKey in innerObject) {
    var t = innerObject[innerKey];
    var ud = $(t).attr('class');
    
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    
    var col1 = document.createElement('td');
    col1.innerText = innerKey;
    row.appendChild(col1);
    
    var col2 = document.createElement('td');
    col2.innerText = t;
    row.appendChild(col2);
    
    html += $(row).html();
  }
}
html += '</table>';
var displayResources = $('#displayResources');
displayResources.html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayResources"></div>
```

Or just escape `<` and `>`

```js
var html = '<table border="1">';
var mainObject = [{"Field1":"<div class=\"row\">something else here</div>"}]
html += '<tr>'
html += '<th id="keypress">KEY</th>';
html += '<th>VALUE</th>';
html += '</tr>';

for (var key in mainObject) {
  var innerObject = mainObject[key];
  for (var innerKey in innerObject) {
    var t = innerObject[innerKey];
    var ud = $(t).attr('class');
    
    html += '<tr>';
    var t = innerObject[innerKey];
    var ud = $(t).attr('class');

    html += '<td>' + innerKey + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + t.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
  }
}
html += '</table>';
var displayResources = $('#displayResources');
displayResources.html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="displayResources"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect "t.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')" is working as i expected. thanks you very much @ Thum Choon Tat

Comment: Yeah marked. You can also mark the question as valid

Answer (score 1):

Your given code snippet is not enough for us to provide a solution but in my opinion I think you could use

```
//Value return from XML HttpRequest
var fieldArr = JSON.parse(returnValue);
var field1 = fieldArr[0].Field1;
```

Comment: No that one is dynamic content, using.field1 wont be a good option.

Comment: oh I see. I will try to find another way